# Unable to create table using php script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is one of my script that I was working on but I just can't figure out what's wrong.

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "str_academy";

$connect = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbusername", "$dbpassword");

if (!$connect) {
   echo("<div class='container'>");         
   echo("<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Warning! </strong>Couldn't create the         specified database</div>");
   echo("</div>");;
exit();
}else {
   echo("<div class='container'>");
   echo("<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Success! </strong>Database connection established successfully</div>");
   echo("</div>");;
}

if ($connect) {
   $database_create = 'CREATE DATABASE str_academy';
   $database_query = mysqli_query($connect, $database_create);
if (!$database_query) {
echo("<div class='container'>");            
    echo("<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Warning! </strong>Couldn't create the specified database</div>");
    echo("</div>");
    exit();         
}else {
    echo("<div class='container'>");
    echo("<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Success! </strong>Database : str_academy successfully created</div>");
    echo("</div>");
}
}

$database_select = mysqli_select_db($connect, "str_academy");

if (!$database_select) {
   echo "Select a database first";
}else {
   echo "Database Selected";
}
$contact_table_create = "CREATE TABLE contact_information (
contact_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
contact_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
contact_email TEXT NOT NULL,
phonenumber INT(11) REAL NULL,
message TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(contact_id)
)";
$contact_table_query = mysqli_query($connect, $contact_table_create);

if (!$contact_table_query) {
   echo "Table not created";
}else {
   echo "Table created";
}   

?>
```

I've created this simple test script. Everything seems to be running perfectly except that it is not creating the table contact_information. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: What does `mysqli_error()` return?

Comment: @Jocelyn It will complain about some syntax error near near `'REAL` :-) But yes, that's the way to get into the debugging of scripts.

Comment: When I try this: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REAL NULL,
message TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(contact_id)
)' at line 5`. Going to postulate that this is something to do with your usage of the `REAL` keyword

Comment: change phonenumber INT(11) REAL NULL, to phonenumber INT(11) NOT NULL, and see if it works

Comment: Well yes, it was about that REAL part. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `REAL` used in this context is throwing a syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REAL NULL,
>   message TEXT NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY(contact_id)
>   )' at line 5

Removing `REAL` from the query (and, if necessary, replacing it with something else) should fix the problems you're having.

Answer (score 1):

change `phonenumber INT(11) REAL NULL,` to `phonenumber INT(11) NOT NULL,` and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

In phpmyadmin / innoDb REAL becomes double so i think you need to replace `REAL` for `double DEFAULT`. Your query will be like:

```
CREATE TABLE contact_information (
    contact_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    contact_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    contact_email TEXT NOT NULL,
    phonenumber double DEFAULT NULL,
    message TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(contact_id)
)
```

Comment: As the comments above shown you can also use `INT(11)` instead of `double DEFAULT`

Answer (score 0):

The error is at the column `phonenumber INT(11) REAL NULL`. This should be `phonenumber INT(11) NOT NULL`

Answer (score -1):

Output the mysqli error message. I suspect the user "root" may not have the `CREATE DATABASE` privileges.

```
if (!$database_query) {
    $error = mysqli_error($connect);
    echo("<div class='container'>");            
    echo("<div class='alert alert-danger'>{$error}</div>");
}
```

Comment: Although they have given negative vote, I agree with the part of the privileges. Recommend that this type of response you keep in the comments. :)